# Sending a linked list through socket in java

Tags: java, serialization, linked-list

I want to send a linked list of objects through TCP socket from server to client, and vice-versa. How can I do that? Should I send just a head of linked list, or is there some other way?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) is `Serializable` so you can send it with `ObjectOutputStream` and its `writeObject` method.

Comment: I am developing a multi player snake game, for two players (in first version of game at least :D ), where each snake is represented by a linked list of points, where each point has its row and column position, and it's "next". But I do not have a clue how to serialize that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LinkedList<T>` which is `Serializable`.

EDIT
The `T` must implement the `Serializable` interface which has no method - This just a marker. Your class may have some fields that are not essential to the object (for instance, a cached value computed from actual properties of the object), these can be declared as `transient`.
Have a look at [the doc of `Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html).

Comment: Seems like a nice solution to me. Thanks :)

Comment: Just remember that the objects `<T>` in the `LinkedList` also need to be `Serialisable`

Comment: Also, for the sake of performance it might be a good idea to send **detlas**  _(changes in the lists)_ back and forth instead of the whole list. I am not sure how much data your linked list contains.

Comment: Linked list does not contain much data, so it's not a problem to send the whole linked list each time. But now I have an issue. How am I supposed to make the objects of my class '<T>' be 'Serialisable'?

Comment: @xpg94 Make it `implements Serializiable`.